# Something special for general finite extension with top field being algebraically closed

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K/F$ be a finite extension with $K$ algebraically closed.

How can I show that $\mathrm{char}(F)=0$ and 
$K=F((-1)^{1/2})$ ?

Comment: You should add the assumption that $K \neq F$, otherwise $K = F = \overline{\mathbb F_p}$ is a counterexample with characteristic $p$.

Comment: This is the [Artin-Schreier Theorem](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf). The link is to an exposition of it by [Keith Conrad](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/619/kcd).

Answer (score 1):

You could show that $F$ is real closed, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field for various equivalent definitions. $\operatorname{char}(F) = 0$ follows from the fact that the field is ordered, and $K = F(\sqrt{-1})$ is one of the equivalent definitions.

**Edit**: As marlu points out, you need $F \neq K$.